# How to get get All checkboxes value in one list Type veriable

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-checkbox

In the following code i want to store all `checkboxes` value in

```
List<integar>ProcedureIDs = new ArrayList<>();
```

but it save only last checked checkbox id.i want to save multiple ids in it...

this is my `recycleView` adapter..

```
public class ProcedureAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<ProcedureAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<LabAppointmentProcedure> labAppointmentProcedureList;
       List<Integer> ProcedureIDs = new ArrayList<>();
    class MyViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        TextView procedureName, procedureId;
        private int procedureID;
        CheckBox checkBox;

        MyViewHolder(final View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

            procedureName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtProcedureName);
            procedureId = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtProcedureId) ;
            checkBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.chkProcedure);

            checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if(isChecked){
                         ProcedureIDs.add(Integer.parseInt(procedureId.getText().toString()));
                       // AppointmentDetails.procedureID = Integer.parseInt(procedureId.getText().toString());
                        //EnterSample.ProcedureID = Integer.parseInt(procedureId.getText().toString());
                        EnterSample.ProcedureSampleIDs =ProcedureIDs;
                    }else{
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    }

    public ProcedureAdapter(List<LabAppointmentProcedure> labAppointmentProceduresList){
        this.labAppointmentProcedureList = labAppointmentProceduresList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i){
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.procedure_row_item,viewGroup,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position){
        LabAppointmentProcedure labAppointmentProcedure = labAppointmentProcedureList.get(position);
        holder.procedureName.setText(labAppointmentProcedure.getProcedure());
        holder.procedureId.setText(String.valueOf(labAppointmentProcedure.getProcedureID()));

        if(holder.checkBox.isChecked()){
            holder.procedureID = labAppointmentProcedureList.get(position).getProcedureID();
            ProcedureIDs.add(Integer.parseInt(holder.procedureId.getText().toString()));
        }

    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){
        return labAppointmentProcedureList.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not clearing or removing items from ProcedureIDs anywhere in your code?

Comment: yes i am just passing it to another class... even am not getting while check....debugging giving me only last store id

Comment: you have to create a boolean variable in your model class and just set true or false according to your need and at the last time just get how many items are true and false